# For loop to eliminate columns in multiple dfs

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I've got about 10 dataframes. For the example, here are two:

```
name <- c("A", "B", "C")
name.footnote <- c("this", "that", "the other")
class <- c("one", "two", "three")
class.footnote <- c("blank", "blank", "blank")

df1 <- data.frame(name, name.footnote, class, class.footnote)
df2 <- data.frame(name, name.footnote, class, class.footnote)
```

When I eliminate columns from them one at a time, my code works fine.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- select(df1, -ends_with("footnote"))
```

I'd like to write a loop to process both dfs with less code, but can't get my loop working right. I keep getting the same error message:

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("select_") :   no applicable method for 'select_'
>  applied to an object of class "character".
> ```

See a few of the many loop codes I've tried, below. What am I missing?

```
listofDfs <- list("df1","df2")
```

1.

```
lapply(listofDfs, function(df){
  df <- select(df, -ends_with("footnote"))
  return(df)
  }
)
```

2.

```
for (i in listofDfs){
  i <- select(i, -ends_with("footnote"))
}
```

Comment: drop the quotes when defining your list `listofDfs <- list(df1,df2)`.  as the error states, when you have the quotes the elements of your list are character instead of the dataframe

Comment: Great--got it. Submit it as an answer so I can mark the question answered?

Comment: You can simplify this down to `library(tidyverse); list(df1, df2) %>% map(select, -ends_with('footnote'))`. Use `lapply` instead of `purrr::map` if you like, or try out `map_df` for convenient simplification to data.frame (though in that case `list(df1, df2) %>% bind_rows() %>% select(-ends_with('footnote'))` would work, too).

Answer (score 2):

Try dropping the quotes when defining your list `listofDfs <- list(df1,df2)`. As the error states, when you have the quotes the elements of your list are character instead of the `data.frame` that `select()` is expecting.

```
library(dplyr)

listofDfs <- list(df1,df2)

#using lapply
list_out1 <- lapply(listofDfs, function(df){
  df <- select(df, -ends_with("footnote"))
  return(df)
})

#using for loop
list_out2 <- vector("list", length(listofDfs))
for (i in seq_along(listofDfs)){
  list_out2[[i]] <- select(listofDfs[[i]], -ends_with("footnote"))
}
```

#### follow up per comment

you can use `get` and `assign` to work with your original character list and manipulate the dfs in your global environment while iterating.

```
listofDfs <- list('df1','df2')

invisible(lapply(listofDfs, function(i){
  df <- select(get(i, globalenv()), -ends_with("footnote"))
  assign(i, df, envir = globalenv())
}))

for (i in listofDfs){
  df <- select(get(i, globalenv()), -ends_with("footnote"))
  assign(i, df, envir = globalenv())
}
```

Comment: Same problem (loop isn't working as efficiently as individual lines), different error. With these loops the two dfs are combined, not saved out as unique dfs. The new dfs should replace the old ones as df1 & df2.

Comment: you want to replace them in your global environment? or in `listofDfs`? and whats the different error?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace them in my global environment, not in the list. No actual error--poor word choice on my part. Just still not quite returning the desired result.

Comment: see edit for working with the objects by name in global as opposed to from the list of the objects

Comment: "Error in get(i, globalenv()) : invalid first argument"

Comment: Working with `df1, df2, ..., dfn` is tortuous in R. Your code will be full of `assign` and `paste("df", n)` and general awkwardness. Working with a `list` is generally preferable to avoid all these issues.